# UITableView and swipe to delete allows multiple rows to be highlighted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have some odd but only mildly annoying behaviour with a `UITableView` that isn't inside a `UITableViewController`.  It's very basic and all plumbed in with the minimal methods required.  In IB it's set to allow single selection, show selection on touch etc.
The following sequence of actions lets you 'highlight' any number of rows:

- Select a row.
- Swipe to delete any row.
- Click anywhere to dismiss the delete action.
- Select a row different than the first.

You'll now have two rows highlighted, this process can be repeated until all are selected.

Why is this possible/what have I missed? The after dismissing the delete option doesn't call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. :/

Comment: just to make sure, allowsMultipleSelection is NO in the UITableView, right?

Comment: It is yes, but it doesn't appear to make any difference.  I'd love to know what swipe to delete does internally, some time I'll dig through it, e.g. whether or not the whole table goes into edit mode etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK a quick read through of all the documentation has led me to the answer.  Although swipe to delete isn't unselecting my rows visibly (due to code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` applying the highlight I want and code in `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` removing it) it is removing it from being the selected row by assigning nil to `indexPathForSelectedRow`.  This is because, as noted in the docs, these calls are not sent when the table is in edit mode which I can only assume the whole table is during swipe to delete.
Seeing as the row is actually deselected all I need to do is remove my custom highlight so I did this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
      willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = self.cardsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    if (selectedIndex != nil) {
        [self tableView:self.cardsTable didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex];
    }
}
```

So I guess my custom table highlight is a bit hackish.